What kind of details are you requesting further?
My last question:
Load extern HTML with fetch returns nothing
was downvoted and closed in few seconds.
I really don't understand what I have to add further.
I added:

a minimal reproducible example (with the shortest code I was able to write)
the expected output (see the screenshot)
my researches (the linked answer where I found the initial code)

But all this stuff is not enough. What else should I add?

That would be an answer, then. But downvoting and closing the question asking for "desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem" when they are already present it seems not fair to me.

These comments were not there when the question was closed @RobertLongson, I agree with the OP that the question seems clear. There were other comments though that are now deleted, maybe that would change the situation (but probably not).

I guess we're missing the HTTP response. What http code is returned for instance?

If I were to nitpick and guess it might be because it starts out with a common pattern often seen where people say there is an error without accompanying details. - "I'm facing troubles...", you do mention that later on but would have made more sense to be a part of the same sentence (Users may have stopped reading post by this point)

@Sayse I removed the first part of the sentence, thanks for the hint. Anyway, it's hard to believe that all the users that downvoted and closed the question did not read it all

I need details why do you use mode: 'no-cors' and what is unclear about the fact that you can't access the response body with mode: 'no-cors'. I didn't vote to close because I was to late but I would vote as duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors#43268098

The question is unclear. What does "What am I missing" mean? Are you asking why you get this behavior or how to enable and configure CORS? That's two different questions.

@jabaa it was just a way to ask: "why the HTTP GET response is empty while my browser shows its content?". About no-cors: I read other similar questions, but I really didn't understand how CORS work, indeed

But even if it is a dup, or I didn't understand something (like anyone asks something here) why do I deserve SIX downvotes? I don't get the point to punish me in such a way. I tried to make my best to write a question according to SO rules.

The downvotes are for the missing research effort. You added mode: 'no-cors' to your code without reading the docs or searching for it on Stack Overflow. Missing research effort is a downvote reason. It's not a punishment. It's a bad question. Asking a duplicate question is usually downvoted.

You don't deserve six downvotes, but some of that could be the meta effect. You also should not delete your question, even if it's a dup. A different observable effect of the same problem can be valuable in helping future developers who experience the same observation to find the dup and thus a solution.

I closed this because you deleted your original question. This question on meta is impossible to answer without seeing your original question on Stack Overflow.

Unfortunately people do vote because of missing shown research effort. Which is just plain wrong and grossly misunderstanding / selectively reading the description of the downvote button, but at this point if you try to convince anyone that likes to think like that they'll just look the other way and go la-la-la-la-la until you're gone.

-6 does seem a bit excessive, but, also, if 6 people found your question and were annoyed that it was lacking response headers and no error text to indicate what the "NetworkError" is and they're all people who are more than willing to vote on posts that deserve votes, then -6 is what you'll get.

@jabaa that's like saying "6 lashes isn't punishment" when one would've sufficed

@java-addict301 Downvotes aren't a punishment. This platform is based on a voting system. The question is unclear and not good. 7 users (87,5% of the voters) downvoted the question and 1 user (12,5% of the voters) upvoted the question. The vote has nothing to do with the asker. We didn't punish the user. We voted the quality of the question. Neither one downvote nor 100 downvotes are a punishment. You should never punish users with downvotes.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I understand, but keeping visible such a downvoted question is humiliating and does not provide anything useful to others

@KevinB I get your point, but that was why I posted the question. Of course if I knew what that error meant, and how the CORS/header work I wouldn't have needed to ask the question!

Reminder: How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? "A lot. Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer—if the information that you need already exists, then you should be able to find it before asking. You want to
Search. Like mad.
Read documentation.
Test your code.
Troubleshoot.
Read blogs.
Find books.
Follow tutorials."

@jabaa if it isn't punishment then it wouldn't take away reputation.

@java-addict301 I vote the quality of a question. I don't punish the user. If you think that the voting/reputation system is wrong or broken, it's a different question. Here, we discuss if the 7 downvotes are appropriate. I think they are. I think, the close reason is correct (the question is still unclear), but I think it should be closed as duplicate. I think, users on Stack Overflow should invest more research effort before asking a question. I don't know the user and I don't want to punish the user. But I want to downvote a bad question and I think, it's a bad question.

@Mark i do agree, i think the issue here is in the weight of voting in general. I don't think people like yourself should feel punished because you asked about something that was a bit outside of your comfort zone, but the post itself does need to be rated correctly so that it'll be handled by the site properly in the long run. That you feel punished is by design, the idea is a mix of both positive and negative reinforcement will push people in the right direction. Even now, downvotes only remove 2 rep compared to upvotes giving 10, but i don't think the rep lost is the thing that hurts.

CORS is one of those topics that I find super frustrating when it comes to people asking questions on SO and i'm probably not alone. The concept hasn't changed significantly since IE finally started supporting it and yet even today people often try to solve these problems in ways that don't make sense because there's so many wrong answers out there on the internet (and even on SO!) about how to solve CORS errors.

@KevinB I'm no fan of canonical answers, but it does sound like one could be of help here. People will still fire from the hip when they see yet another "make my cors problem go away" question, but at least if its with dupe closure ammunition then there will not be a gaping hole left afterwards.

@jabaa definitions are the foundation for any discussion, and downvotes are literally the definition of 'punishment' according merriam webster.  If we're not willing to call things what they are, we're not starting from a point from which we can continue any meaningful discussion thereafter.  It doesn't matter why you vote - your intentions have nothing to do with it.

@jabaa that said, I do agree with your sentiment regarding research and asking questions on SO - I just think it's also important to recognize what downvoting is.

Guys, I'm aware I cannot tell you what I did before posting the question, how much time I spent trying to understand how the things work (and honestly, still now I'm not sure to fully understand them). But there are a lot of people here who got zillion of votes with very poor questions, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-mean or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/loop-for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476

Just to say, I see different criteria among users. I can accept my question was not perfect, but I showed more effort than the examples above (o many others!)

@Mark The linked questions are 12 and 16 years old. Much has changed since then, especially in the last 5 years.

@Mark I can't argue or judge because I can't see your question, but you are probably right anyway. It changes nothing though. It was way too easy to ask any old question and earn buckets of reputation points when the site was young because it was empty and rules were lax; that situation has flipped. It is now too full and everything is hard, especially asking well-received questions. Draw your own conclusions from it.
